# How to click on the text button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm trying to click on select button using xpath and css selector but it doesn't works

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="section-select-all"]').click()
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#results-container > form > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > div > button').click()
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results-container"]/form/ul/li[1]/div/div/button').click()
```

please let me know how it would be here is the code

```
<div class="section-actions"><button type="button" class="section-select-all">Select 50<span class="screen-reader-text"> for section Dec 11, 2015</span></button></div>
```

Comment: How many buttons you want clicked?

Comment: If you have issues with the Xpath or CSS queries, you can use the developer tools in Chrome and Firefox to check that your desired web element gets selected. Simply use the console and type $$("CSS query") or $.x("XPath query")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `elements` that will not work. Use `element` instead. I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.If there is a single button then try:

**Example 1 -**

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("section-select-all").click()
```

If multiple buttons with same class name then you can use this:

**Example 2 -**

```
buttons = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("section-select-all")
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

If the buttons are in a frame, then make sure you switch to the frame before clicking on it.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: @Bostan - I hope `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` Or chrome.

Comment: @Bostan - Please make sure the spelling of `element[s]` is correct. In the first example, I used `example` and in the second I used `elements`. If you want to click on `elements` then you need to iterate through the list (like I did in the 2nd example).